# Laravel 5: return view not working on mac

Tags: php, macos, laravel-5

Running this

```
view()->exists('welcome')
```

returns true.
But running this

```
return view('welcome');
```

** showing blank white screen **

I just installed Laravel on my mac,
Any ideas?

This is with Laravel Framework version 5.0 and above-dev

Comment: Is error reporting on?
Show us your view code!

Comment: Same view as you installed Laravel from their site..nothing different.